# Compare two lists and find the unique values

Tags: python

I had just started with Python and have no real programming experience except SQL.

My task:

1. Find words that exists on both even and odd lines.
2. Words that only exists on even lines
3. Words that only exists on odd lines

All punctuations and uppercase are removed so we dont need to worry about that. However, it is several words on the same line

The output should look something like this

```
Common words on both lines: ['I', 'the', 'am', 'all', 'as', ...] 
Only even lines : ['yellow', 'christmas', 'smell', ...] 
Only odd lines: ['yours', 'war', 'may', 'remote', ...]
```

I started like

```
evens, odds = set(), set()
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    for index, row in enumerate(f):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            evens.update(row.split())
        else:
            odds.update(row.split())
commons = sorted(evens & odds)
```

How should I continue from here? My main problem is to print out the unique words for evens and odds. A minor problem is to transpose my list in commons to a row.

Comment: look up "set" keyword in python

Comment: You should post a sample of the txt file before your expected output

Comment: I believe set difference can be achieved using `unique = evens - odds` (minus operator)

Comment: Thanks. I used the function set. <pre> commons = sorted(evens & odds)
unique_odds=set(odds-evens)
unique_evens=set(evens-odds) <code>. How can I include it in my main query so the output will be like this? <pre>unique_odds: ['yours', 'war', 'may', 'remote', ...]<code> . Guess I need to transpose it in some way

Answer (score 3):

Use the difference operator `-`:

```
only_odd = odd - even
```

Comment: Note `-` is syntactic sugar for [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.difference).

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is an important concept to learn, if you want to use python regularly.

**So you can try for problem statement 1**:

```
combine=['I', 'the', 'am', 'all', 'as','yellow'] 
even_line=['yellow', 'christmas', 'smell']
odd_line=['yours', 'war', 'may', 'remote','yellow']

words_in_both_odd_even=[i for i in combine for j in even_line for k in odd_line if (i==j and i==k)]

words_in_both_odd_even
```

**For problem statement 2:**

```
words_in_even_line=[i for i in combine for j in even_line if (i==j)]
words_in_even_line
```

**For problem statement 3:**

```
words_in_odd_line=[i for i in combine for k in odd_line if (i==k)]

words_in_odd_line
```

**If you are looking for unique values in any of the above there problem statement output-** Then you can use `set(words_in_both_odd_even)` or `set(words_in_even_line)` or `set(words_in_odd_line)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to know the common word in even and odd lines, you need to get two lists of the words of even and odd lines.This is how to make two lists of these.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKGlu.png)

Then you have to find the common words exists in two lists.If the word is a common word of two lists, delete this word from two lists and add it to the new list of common words.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJBRW.png)